# How can I make each box expand when I click read more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been having a problem, I want whenever I click read more it should popup and expand like the image,

[image]

Solution I have tried; I have tried the generic readmore, but I noticed the column beside the one with the readmore also stretches when I click the readmore.

So what I want is whenever I click the readmore it animates to the center of the screen and have a close button.

Thank you in advance, this is the codepen (with full code)

https://codepen.io/tickatop/pen/QXgaoJ

Part code of the css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10;
}

#more {display: none;}

.flexContainer{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly sure what exactly you're asking here but if you want a pop up with read more you should use a Modal. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Read more</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum
      vitae. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui. Quisque id diam
      vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Diam in arcu cursus euismod quis. Ut consequat semper viverra
      nam libero justo laoreet sit amet. Magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in. Enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit. Malesuada fames
      ac turpis egestas sed. Enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. In pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae. Sit amet justo donec enim diam
      vulputate ut pharetra sit. Neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec. Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Non blandit massa enim nec. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque
      habitant. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Furthermore if you want the appearance of the Modal to be zoom in like on the other container on your CodePen you should look into using JQuery UI transitions. You can define your own keyframes in CSS (but its a harder job)

Comment: Thank you, not like the other container, just the container with the readmore, I would look at your solution and give a feedback